# Add double quotes to any Int in the python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataset, and I want to add (sround) to any `number` a double quotes `""`,such as `2` to `"2"`. I don't know how to write this code. Here is a sample of dataset:

```
 {0: {"address": 0,
             "ctag": "TOP",
             "deps": defaultdict(<class "list">, {"ROOT": [6, 51]}),
             "feats": "",
             "head": "",
             "lemma": "",
             "rel": "",
             "tag": "TOP",
             "word": ""},
         1: {"address": 1,
             "ctag": "Ne",
             "deps": defaultdict(<class "list">, {"NPOSTMOD": [2]}),
             "feats": "_",
             "head": 6,
             "lemma": "اشرف",
             "rel": "SBJ",
             "tag": "Ne",
             "word": "اشرف"},
```

I tried like:

```
rep = [int(s) for s in str.split() if s.isdigit()]
```

Comment: the double quotes arent just there for show. They represent strings. convert int to strings and you're done. Good luck!

Comment: @ParitoshSingh, It's inside a dataset, and the length is also not clear, can you describe in code.

Comment: wheres your [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh, I mentioned that I don't know how to start my code.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh python will not use double quotes by itself but rather single quotes. This is more like a `json.dumps` kinda thing, but generally only applies to the integer keys, unless the OP also casts the values to strings.

Comment: i'd encourage you to then figure out how to start your code, by following some tutorials online. take it one step at a time. 1st, some python basics, 2nd reading that structure into your code, 3rd, altering it, 4th saving it back.

Comment: And on that basis, there really is no need to have the double quotes unless you're trying to serialize into a specific format

Comment: @ParitoshSingh, yes, I also tried this code `k = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', file)
print(k)`, but it change to single

Comment: @ParitoshSingh, Thanks for encouraging me, I proceed learning, but I have task as well to do it. Therefore, sometimes, I do share here. As you know the JSON does not support single quote and I have to add a double qoutes to the dataset.

Comment: have you looked at what `json.dumps()` does? sounds like you asked the question of how to swim over the river, when you actually just want to go to the other side and there is a bridge within sight…, no harm meant, but sometimes the full story helps. oops, missed the earlier ref to json.dumps

Comment: @ahed87, Yes, I tried with `json.dumps()`, but the problem is that it gives me output like: `[\"0\", \"0\", \"6\", \"51\", \"1\", \"1\",]` that seems to stay on the river is a better choice. haha

Comment: pass you regular python object without tampering and it should automatically become valid json, if not there would be a lot of python webprogrammers that would get gray hairs… :-)

Comment: But show me how? I tried several ways but does not give me any result.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following code, it changes to double quotes with a slash:

```
import re
import json

f1 = open('../data/parse.txt', 'r')
file = f1.read()
k = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', file)
j= json.dumps(json.dumps(k))
print(j)
```

Here is the result:

```
[\"0\", \"0\", \"6\", \"51\", \"1\", \"1\", \"2\", \"6\", \"2\", \"2\", \"1\", \"3\", \"3\", \"4\", \"6\", \"4\", \"4\", \"3\", \"5\", \"5\", \"6\", \"6\", \"6\", \"3\", \"5\", \"7\", \"1\", \"0\", \"7\", \"7\"]
```

Comment: If this is your expected output and the answer you needed, please hit the green checkmark to accept your answer and close this question for future users, thanks.

Comment: @davedwards, unfortunately does not match perfectly to my answer, as I want it like: `"4", "6", "1"....`, but it gives with `\"1\"`. still I need help.

Comment: Do any of the other answers offered here provide a working solution?

Comment: No, none of them works for my dataset, as it has a complex structure, and I cannot change the structure of them manually. Because the dataset is growing daily.

Comment: what if you try `k = re.sub(r'(\d+)', r'"\1"', file)`, then `print(k) `, does not produce the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Let's summarize:

1. You only have the data as files on the format shown, and not python objects.
2. For the reason mentioned in the q, those files are not usable for you.
   btw, you have not explained why you can't use the data (or where it's not usable).
3. The files are generated by python (string contains literal defaultdict),
   looks like piped `print` statements to a text file?

First recommendation is that you change the way these files are generated to a way which allows easy and secure round-trips to disk. `json.dump / json.load` is an easy way to go. Could also use `pickle`, but that is more sensitive to versions, and opens up for malicious code.

**How to fix your current problem.**

Based on your given info this will work, but breaks easily. You should also know where the data comes from, since it's not a very secure way of parsing data.

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict
# read your file as string into file_data
file_data = """{0: {"address": 0,
  "ctag": "TOP",
  "deps": {"ROOT": [6, 51]},
  "head": ""},
 1: defaultdict(<class "list">, {0: [1]})}"""
python_object = eval(file_data)
# now the above line errors out on py36
# on py36 the repl for defafaultdict is: defaultdict(list, {0: [1]})
# so that has to match your version of python to go through eval without errors...
# the below line works on py36
python_object = eval(file_data.replace('<class "list">', 'list'))
print(json.dumps(python_object))
```

outputs

```
'{"0": {"address": 0, "ctag": "TOP", "deps": {"ROOT": [6, 51]}, "head": ""}, "1": {"0": [1]}}'
```

*If this indeed fixes your issue... It sounded like your question arose as a professional, in that case please donate some hours of your pay or time to a good cause of your choise.*

**Original** part based on incomplete picture.

an example of using the standard json library, which does produce generally valid json, but then one can wonder what your consumer of json conforms to…

```
import json

data = {0: {"address": 0,
             "ctag": "TOP",
             "deps": {"ROOT": [6, 51]},
             "feats": "",
             "head": ""}}

print(json.dumps(data))

with open('data.json', 'wt') as fj:
    json.dump(data, fj)
```

outputs

```
{"0": {"address": 0, "ctag": "TOP", "deps": {"ROOT": [6, 51]}, "feats": "", "head": ""}}
```

if the standard json does not work with your consumer, let us know.

Comment: Unfortunately, for my dataset, it gives this output.` {0: {'address': 0,
                 'ctag': 'TOP',
                 'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'ROOT': [6, 51]}),`

Comment: it's because your data is just a string and not a structured object.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but your solution gives me this error as you mentioned, I tried with different version of python but still have the error.   `File "<string>", line 5
    1: defaultdict(<class "list">, {0: [1]})} `

Comment: what matters is that you replace the signature of `defaultdict` you have in your textfiles with the same as you have on the python you are on. just make a simple dict and print it, like such `dd = defaultdict(list); print(dd[0].append(1))` and then make sure that what you put into `eval` is matching the beginning of the printed test dict, i.e. the `replace` to make it work on py36 for me. if you still have errors then it's hidden in the data, and you will need to clean that. but that cleaning only you can figure out, since you are the only one that has the data...

Comment: so what do you get when you have made the `.replace` to something matching, the line `python_object = eval(file_data.replace('<class "list">', 'list'))` does work for me, so it's up to you to make the correct match to make it work on your computer.

Comment: In your solution, you deleted the Dari text, while I included it gives me in unicode,` "1": {"address": 1, "ctag": "Ne", "deps": {"NPOSTMOD": [2]}, "feats": "", "head": "", "lemma": "\u0627\u0634\u0631\u0641", "rel": "SBJ", "tag": "Ne", "word": "\u0627\u0634\u0631\u0641"}}`